# is it possible to pass parameters to an assoc array?

Tags: php, parameter-passing

think about an array like this:

```
...
"key1" => some_call("val1", $params),
"key2" => some_call("val1", $params),
...
```

now i want to pass parameters ($params) when addressing my array entries

```
$x = $array['key1'] , $params ...
```

is there some way to do something like this?

**UPDATE**

why would i like to do this?
i am using codeigniter and in the language file is an assoc array, where the right side holds the text in its predicted language. i want to abuse this a little bit and want to load
email templates, where i pass a parameter which holds the values which shell be replaced in the template.

**UPDATE 2**

for php 5.2.*

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? `"key1" => some_call("val1", $params)` will add the return value of `some_call("val1", $params)` to the array.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you're trying to achieve with your code ... maybe there's an easier solution to your problem (which may not be the parameter-part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PHP 5.3 you can use anonymous functions. Maybe you want something like this:

```
<?php

function some_call($arg,$params)
{
     echo "$arg: ",count($params),"\n";
}

$array = array(
    'key1' => function($params) { some_call('val1',$params); },
    'key2' => function($params) { some_call('val1',$params); }
);

$array['key1'](array(1,2,3));
```

Comment: can i install/plugin that feature on a 5.2.1 version, anyway?

Comment: You could use `create_function` but you **will not**. Or you could defined normal non-lambda functions. Another variant is compiling the PHP 5.3 source to PHP 5.2 source using [prephp](http://github.com/nikic/prephp). But I don't think that this is already stable enough.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of anonymous functions (i.e. if you're using PHP5 < 5.3) then you could use the [create_function()](http://www.php.net/create_function) function to achieve what you want:

```
function some_call($arg, $params)
{
     echo $arg, ': ', count($params), "\n";
}

$array = array(
    'key1' => create_function('$params', 'some_call("val1", $params);'),
    'key2' => create_function('$params', 'some_call("val2", $params);'),
);

$array['key1'](array(1,2,3));
```

Comment: for use in real code: 'key1' => create_function('$params', 'return some_call("val1", $params);'). then i can directly access the result

Answer (score 1):

Make $x an array?

```
$x[] = $array['key1'] , $params ...
```

or

```
$x = array($array['key1'] , $params ... )
```

or a concatenated string

```
$x = $array['key1'] . $params ... // use the . to concat
```